# How do I access my inherited widget in a dart file that doesn't build a widget in the tree?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, inherited-widget

I'm following [this example](https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/inherited-widgets) to add my very first `InheritedWidget` into my app. I've created my `_state_container.dart` file and now want to use it.

To start, I'd like to use it in the widget where I display the chats in a group chat. This widget is in the file `receivedChats.dart` (chat header). I see in the example that all I would need to do is instantiate the `container` in the target's widget build function, but the problem is that this widget is calling another file called `message_dao.dart` to handle all data from Firebase. This file doesn't have a widget build function, so how would I use the container here?

**File Structure:**

```
main.dart
|
wrapper.dart
|
home.dart //or authenticate.dart if user is not logged in
|
chatScreen.dart
|               |
msgInput.dart   receivedChats.dart - message_dao.dart
```

This is what I've already tried, but it gives 2 errors:

```
class MessageDao {

  final container = StateContainer.of(context); //ERROR: Undefined name 'context'. 
  final chatState = container.chatState; //ERROR: The instance member 'container' can't be accessed in an initializer. 

  //...rest of code...//
```

Answer (score 0):

its a class, Dart classes are the blueprint of the object, or it can be called object constructors. its just not initialize yet. just like that `StateContainer` it self;

```
class MessageDao {
 //here :
 final StateContainerState container;
 
 MessageDao(this.container);

 chatstate(){
 return container.chatState;
 }
}
```

you need to initialize it somewhere in your code when there is an actual build context that can be passed to:

```
final messageDaoState = MessageDao(StateContainer.of(context));

final chatstate = messageDaoState.chatstate();
```

Comment: The 2nd to last line (`final messageDaoState = ...`) gives this error: `The argument type 'StateContainerState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StateContainer'.`

Comment: if `StateContainer.of(context)` return type is `StateContainerState`, then you should declare as that, change final `StateContainer container` to ` final StateContainerState container;`

Comment: i idited my answer for you